# 4 Byte int Value Overflow

Tags: c, memory, int, overflow

Me and my friend did the following on different computers:
[image]

But the result of both computers came out the same. Shouldn't memory give the address of a random place when the variable overflows?

Comment: No. It is just overflows and gives the last 32 bit of the result which will be some random like value without its non existent upper part.

Comment: Overflowing has nothing to do with addresses.

Comment: So what are the numbers on the screen when there is an overflow?

Comment: Signed `int` overflow is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p5).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, I know.  But strange that it works the same on two different computers ?

Comment: @thinkblue What's "different"?  If they're both running on x86 hardware, for example, the underlying instruction set is almost certainly exactly the same for `int` calculations.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Undefined behavior means you cannot know what will happen at runtime. But I was surprised that it gave the same result as if it was known.
So, is the result here a random address in memory?

Comment: As defined in the C standard, “undefined behavior” means the C standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior. It does not mean you cannot know what will happen when the program is executed. That depends on things other than the C standard. The fact that the C standard does not have rules for it does not mean the rules about how the processor works do not apply or that the source code of the compiler itself misbehaves or that other factors or rules limiting the behavior do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

A common behavior of processors is for integer multiply instructions to return the low bits of the mathematical product. For example, when multiplying a 32-bit number by a 32-bit number, the full mathematical product can be expressed in 64 bits (with some adjustments depending on whether the operands are signed or unsigned types), but the processor will put the low 32 bits of that product in the destination register.

In the product you show, 2 • 4 • 6 • … • 22 • 24, the low 32 bits of the mathematical product are cfc00000 (expressed in hexadecimal). When those bits are interpreted as a two’s complement number, the value is −809500672, since the high bit (used for the sign) is set.

So this is a common result of overflow in the product you evaluated. This behavior is not defined by the C standard, and other results can occur instead.

Comment: I understand what's happening now. I have one more question for you. At the university we are told that a random value is printed from memory on the screen in case of overflow. What is the truth of that ? I understand from the comment you wrote above that this event is not simple. Thanks.

Comment: @thinkblue: If meant literally, the statement is false; computers certainly do not generate a **random** value in case of overflow. But some people use the word “random” carelessly, instead meaning that some perhaps uncontrolled value is printed. This is also not entirely true. As shown in this answer, the value is not controlled by the C standard, but it is affected by other factors, such as how the computer processor works. But there are other factors as well, such as optimization by the compiler transforming the program in unexpected ways, so the result will not necessarily be −809500672.

Comment: @thinkblue: So, to start with, the answer is “It is complicated.” If you know enough about how things work, you can expect certain behaviors, with various caveats. But there is a lot to learn about many things involved in compiling, linking, and executing a program.

Comment: First of all, I am grateful to you for being the only one who answered my questions. I hope one day I can be a software developer like you :)